# In a $\triangle PQR$, $\cos P + \cos Q + \cos R = 2 - \cos Q$, find $\frac{p + r}{q}$ where $p$, $q$, $r$ are side lengths

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

> In a $\triangle PQR$, $\cos P + \cos Q + \cos R = 2 - \cos Q,$
> find $\dfrac{p + r}{q}$ (where $p$, $q$, $r$ are side lengths of $\triangle PQR)$.

For solving this question I was given 4 minutes. I tried using **cosine law**, but equation started becoming more difficult.

There must be a shorter way to find $\frac{p + r}{q}$, but I can't get it.

I also tried
$$\cos P + \cos R = 2(1 - \cos Q)$$
$$\implies 2\cos(\frac{P + R}{2})\cos(\frac{P - R}{2}) = 4 \sin^2\frac{Q}{2}$$
$$\implies \cos(\frac{P - R}{2}) = 2\sin\frac{Q}{2}$$
but I have no idea how to get the required ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second approach is on the right track.
We can continue from there.

Multiply the last equation by $2\cos\frac Q2$.

$$2\cos\frac Q2\cos\left(\frac{P-R}2\right)=4\sin\frac Q2\cos\frac Q2$$
$$2\sin\left(\frac{P+R}2\right)\cos\left(\frac{P-R}2\right)=2\sin Q$$

Note that this is

$$\sin P+\sin R=2\sin Q$$
$$\frac{\sin P+\sin R}{\sin Q}=2$$

According to sin rule, we can write,

$$\frac{p+r}q=2$$
$\square$